# Pinning value types with GCHandle.Alloc

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, garbage-collection, unsafe-pointers

Is it possible to pin pass an int by reference to a method that will then pin that variable in memory so that I can access it with a pointer?

I'm trying to use GCHandle.Alloc to temporarily pin an int in memory so that I can safely store a pointer to that integer. When I try to set the value of the int via the pointer stored in the GCHandle, my integer doesn't get updated.  If I create a pointer to the int using unsafe code, I can successfully change the int. It seems like the int is being passed by value, and I"m setting a different int than the one that actually got pinned. Here is an example of the issue I am currently facing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var count = 8001;
            var mc = MyClass.New(ref count);
            
            mc.Process();
        }
    }

    public unsafe sealed class MyClass
    {
        private GCHandle handle;
        private readonly int* countPtr;
        private MyClass(GCHandle handle, ref int totalCount)
        {
            this.handle = handle;
            fixed (int* p = &totalCount)
                countPtr = p;
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            var value = 9001;
            var handlePtr = (int*)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

            *handlePtr = (int)value; // count is unchanged
            *countPtr = (int)value; // IT'S OVER 9000!

            handle.Free();
        }

        public static MyClass New(ref int count)
        {
            var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(count, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            return new MyClass(handle, ref count);
        }
    }
}
```

The memory addresses of handlePtr and countPtr are different, which leads me to believe that what I think is pinned is not pinned... and I may be building a ticking timebomb into my application.

Use Case:

I have a custom data access layer that uses the following API

```
public IEnumerable<Rows> CallMyProcedure(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalCount)
{
    var rows = Call()
        .SetParameter("PageIndex", pageIndex)
        .SteParameter("PageSize", pageSize)
        .EnumerateDataSet(commandTimeoutSeconds: 60);
    
    return rows;
}
```

Call() starts to build a context of how the stored procedure will be setup at runtime. SetParameter and several other methods add data to the context that will be used when the StoredProcedure is executed.  EnumerateData sets up an IEnumerable state machine that executes the stored procedure with an SqlDataReader that yields on each row.

Some stored procedures use Offset / Fetch in order to retrieve a limited number of results.  In these cases I need to also output the total number of rows using an Sql Output parameter

```
public IEnumerable<Rows> CallMyProcedure(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalCount)
{
    var count = 0;
    var rows = Call()
        .SetParameter("PageIndex", pageIndex)
        .SteParameter("PageSize", pageSize)
        .OutputTotalCount(x=> count = x)
        .EnumerateDataSet(commandTimeoutSeconds: 60)
        .ToList();
    
    totalCount = count;
    return rows;
}
```

The Action I am passing will be executed after all the rows are enumerated and the SqlDataReader is closed, as this is the only way to get an OutPutParameter from an SQL Stored Procedure. As such the only reason that this works is because I am calling .ToList().  If I don't call .ToList() the out totalCount gets set to 0, the method returns and Action to set count gets fired after the reading through all the rows.

I'm looking to add an additional OutputTotalCount overload in order to be able to use do

```
public IEnumerable<Rows> GetAllData()
{
    var count = 0;
    return CallMyProcedure(1, int.MaxValue, out count);
}

public DataPage GetDataPage(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = 0;
    var list = CallMyProcedure(pageIndex, pageSize, out count).ToList()
    
    return new DataPage
    {
        Data = list,
        TotalCount = count
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Rows> CallMyProcedure(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalCount)
{
    totalCount = 0; // Needed because we are leaving this method before setting
    var rows = Call()
        .SetParameter("PageIndex", pageIndex)
        .SteParameter("PageSize", pageSize)
        .OutputTotalCount(ref totalCount)
        .EnumerateDataSet(commandTimeoutSeconds: 60)
    
    return rows;
}
```

The new OutPutTotalCount overload here essentially adds an Instance of MyClass to the context that EnumerDataSet will use to execute the stored procedure when GetEnumerator is called. Process will be called after all the rows have been read. The GCHandles are also tracked by the execution context and are free'd inside of a try/finally.

Comment: I think the integer is being boxed in the call to GCHandle.Alloc(), which would mean you're correct, it's pointing to the wrong integer.

Comment: Do you think that it is incorrectly pointing at the boxed value and actually has the expected value pinned?  Is there a way to tell this with VS2013 / Resharper?

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct. Try boxing the int yourself. `object oi = i; var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(oi, GCHandleType.Pinned); int *pi = (int*) gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();` Then, `*pi += 1` should be reflected in oi.

Comment: Your GCHandle is pointing to the boxed *copy* of the int. But when you take an unsafe pointer to the int, that pointer is pointing to the actual int on the stack. So, to avoid unsafe pointers, you'll have to work with a boxed int, which will pin as expected.

Comment: Are you aware that if `count` runs out of scope, you will lose it? It's _dangerous_ to hold a pointer to a variable on a stack which might live longer than the scope. I'm sure it will be boxed, because it will create a copy on the heap.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the way to get the `count` value by using a ref method which is only executed when iterated. There are several outcomes are possible

Comment: I am aware that if count runs out of scope that it would cause issues. I wasn't going to let this leave my IDE until I was sure this pointer was safe. I was trying to make it safe by pinning the int in order to prevent it to from being collected, but overlooked that it was on the stack and GCHandle.Alloc was boxing a copy onto the heap. I've been looking for a way to get count for a while, but sadly lammdas and ref were the only two methods I could think of. Thank you both for helping me see the error in my logic.